# How do i set up a SOAP webservice

Tags: c#, soap

First off a little context, I work for a channel manager company that builds custom endpoints for their clients to talk to. We currently mostly code in c#.

This is the first time we are connecting with a client that asked us to support a soap web service.

Sadly, we don't have previous experience in this and I can't find any concrete explanations to what it looks like to support a SOAP call.

Currently, it looks like that I have to simply use text processing methods to run through the received XML and parse it in a non-generic way.

But this feels like there should be a more straightforward approach since the protocol is almost 20 years old.

For almost every search result I only get examples of what the XML looks like, but what I'm interested in, is what I need to implement in my application to host an endpoint for the client to successfully post and receive a SOAP message from. And if there is a way to do this without something like XmlWriters/Readers.

Anything to help me get on my way mary is appreciated!

Greetings, Davey

Comment: You can use WCF to build a web service and consume it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I think I'm missing something crucial here and I feel dumb for it. I'm building the endpoint they need to consume. So I know I can use WCF to build a web service, but how do I make that web service SOAP?

Comment: WCF allows you building multiple types of services (not only web btw), including SOAP services. For an example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598157/Building-SOAP-Message-Based-Web-Services-with-WCF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is the least outdated library for offering SOAP.

When you can define the contracts then you're in luck, that's just writing a C# interface.

But when necessary you can also import WSDL specifications and generate C# from that.

> it looks like that I have to simply use text processing methods to run through the received XML and parse it

Don't even consider that. Everything is under control of schemas. And you will also have to generate valid return packages.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm gonna look into this and might have a question later, but at least this helps me get on track! Case closed :)